# Split column on first occurence of '-'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with column that contain house numbers and a suffix. The house number and suffix are seperated by a '-' although many suffixes also contain a '-'.

I have tried this:

```
df house_nr(x):
    y = x['house_nr'].split('-', maxsplit = 1)
    return y

df['suffix'] = df.apply(house_nr, axis=1)
```

Got the following error:

```
KeyError: ('house_nr', 'occurred at index 0')
```

After some other attempts I've got this working:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['house_nr'].str.split('-',1).tolist(),columns = ['house-number','suffix'])
```

And then I join the dataframe but I don't think this solution is very nice or  pythonic.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your dataframe and a desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'house_nr': ['123-Rd-thing', '456-House', '567-House-thing']})
```

```
          house_nr
0     123-Rd-thing
1        456-House
2  567-House-thing
```

Using a list comprehension and `split`, which will be faster than pandas string methods:

```
pd.DataFrame([i.split('-', 1) for i in df.house_nr], columns=['num', 'suffix'])

   num       suffix
0  123     Rd-thing
1  456        House
2  567  House-thing
```

Answer (score 2):

### Using Numpy's defchararray module

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import split

a = df.house_nr.values.astype(str)
pd.DataFrame(
    split(a, '-', 1).tolist(),
    df.index, ['house-number', 'suffix'])

  house-number       suffix
0          123     Rd-thing
1          456        House
2          567  House-thing
```

---

### Same idea with different construction

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import split

cols = ['house-number', 'suffix']
a = df.house_nr.values.astype(str)
pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(cols, zip(*(split(a, '-', 1))))), df.index)

  house-number       suffix
0          123     Rd-thing
1          456        House
2          567  House-thing
```

### Setup Borrowed From @user3483203

(I'll give it back)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'house_nr': ['123-Rd-thing', '456-House', '567-House-thing']})
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `expand=True` and `n=1` arguments to `str.split`. `expand=True` creates new columns for your split, and `n=1` limits the split to the first occurrence of `-`

```
>>> df
          col
0  5-suffix-1
1  6-suffix-2

df[['house_number','suffix']] = df['col'].str.split('-', n=1, expand=True)

>>> df
          col house_number    suffix
0  5-suffix-1            5  suffix-1
1  6-suffix-2            6  suffix-2
```